# Fetching Duplicated Records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query my postgres database for similar query parameters based on two different instances either by names or by phone numbers. I also want to know the column that brings about the match.

I have used the Ilike statement but this does not seem to be well efficient and accurate.

```
select t.* 
from tax_payer  t 
where t.display_name ilike ('tob') or t.phone_number ilike('08162507399') and t.tax_payer_type = 'CORPORATE' 

Name | PhoneNumber | taxIdenityNumber
tobi | 08162507399 | 12345
tob  | 08162507633 | 12346
tobiss| 081625674  | 1234
jogn  | +23408162507399 | 123467
doe  | 0708732562 | 12345
```

I want to get a result that has a similar display name and similar phone number, and also where the similarity is happening.

Expected result from the data should be

```
Name | PhoneNumber | taxIdenityNumber
tobi | 08162507399 | 12345 
tob  | 08162507633 | 12346
tobiss| 081625674  | 1234
jogn  | +23408162507399 | 123467
```

If possible want to know the column that brings about the match.

This will be escalated to the user that either the phone number, name or both is causing the match.

Comment: ok. And what is your problem with that?

Comment: combining `and` and `or` without using parentheses is usually an error. did you mean: `(t.display_name ilike (?1) or t.phone_number ilike(?2)) and t.tax_payer_type = 'CORPORATE'`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a `case` statement in your select:

```
select t.* , 
  case 
    when t.display_name ilike ('tob') then 'Display Name'
    else 'Phone Number'
  end as reason
from tax_payer  t 
where (t.display_name ilike ('tob') or t.phone_number ilike('08162507399')) and t.tax_payer_type = 'CORPORATE'
```

This example would add a column called `reason` with either 'Display Name' or 'Phone Number' as value.

In case you also want to indicate when both are matching:

```
select t.* , 
  case 
    when t.display_name ilike ('tob') and t.phone_number ilike('08162507399') then 'Both'
    when t.display_name ilike ('tob') then 'Display Name'
    else 'Phone Number'
  end as reason
from tax_payer  t 
where (t.display_name ilike ('tob') or t.phone_number ilike('08162507399')) and t.tax_payer_type = 'CORPORATE'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, We are almost there, Except that I don't get "Both" when its the same display name and phone number. Also, values like +234816250739 do not match with 08162507399. I wish to get the results when values are very close. I wish I know how to use free text.

Comment: The 'Both' case should match when the condition is met. Please make sure these variables are templated if you template the ones in your where clause. As for the 'almost'-matching: this is really difficult and seems a bit out of scope of your original question :)

Comment: Thanks. If you check the result sample I gave, u will notice that I wanted a close match. But this works for the system. I will improve it over time. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're very welcome! If you think this answer has solved your problem sufficiently, would you mind to flag it as such? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can list the columns of similarity using string concatenation:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when t.display_name ilike 'tob' then 'display_name;' end) ||
        (case when t.phone_number ilike '08162507399' then 'phone_number;' end) ||
        (case when t.tax_payer_type ilike 'CORPORATE' then 'tax_payer_type;' end)
       ) as column_matches
from tax_payer  t 
where t.display_name ilike 'tob' or
      t.phone_number ilike '08162507399' and
      t.tax_payer_type = 'CORPORATE' ;
```

Or, as I might prefer, a lateral join:

```
select t.*,
       v.match_names
from tax_payer t inner join lateral
     (select string_agg(name) as match_names, count(*) as num_matches
      from (values (t.display_name, 'tob' 'display_name'),
                   (t.phone_number, '08162507399', 'phone_number'),
                   (t.tax_payer_type, 'CORPORATE', 'tax_payer_type')
           ) v(col, pat, name)
       where v.col ilike v.pat
     ) v
order by num_matches desc;
```

Comment: I get this error when I run the query - " subquery in FROM must have an alias Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo".

Answer (score 0):

Why everyone in the above answers they are using "Case" condition I don't know. Its a simple, you need to add few small changes in the script.

select t.* 
from tax_payer  t 
where ((t.display_name ilike ('tob%')) or (t.phone_number ilike('%08162507399%'))) and t.tax_payer_type = 'CORPORATE';

It will result exactly what you showed in the Result table.